# Change localScale.x in Unity without creating a new Vector3

Tags: unity, transformation, scale

Is it possible to change localScale.x in Unity without creating a new Vector3?

Comment: What's the problem with `transform.localScale = new Vector3(changedXScale, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);` that you're trying to solve? This can be expressed in several different ways, depending on your objective.

Comment: @DMGregory, I was worried about the performance and the answer tackled the issue. Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply write: `localScale.x = 100.0` or whatever you'd like.

This doesn't work when the `localScale` you're referring to (which is not clear) is a *property* of some instance, because C# properties are just syntactic sugar for function invocations and you'd thus be changing a member of a local temporary, not the *actual* backing `Vector3`. In those cases you must replace the entire `Vector3`, as in `foo.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, z);`.

This may be a minor inconvenience in terms of typing, but since `Vector3` is a value type there is no appreciable performance overhead (you're not creating garbage on the heap, for example, as you would if `Vector3` was a reference type).